# File sharing in android 2.3 via Bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, connection, file-sharing

I am working on application in which members can share data among each other . I have done it with wi-fi but having problem in Bluetooth . I am in doubt that is it possible to share data among different members at one time via Bluetooth. For example one member has some data and other members want to access that data via Bluetooth . Like two way communication via Bluetooth .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can only be 7 or 8 slaves in Bluetooth Connection . But in P2P communication via Bluetooth you can face problem for example when you will be sending file to other member then other members will be in waiting state & you have to tell them like an alert that how much they have to wait.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple:

With bluetooth you need to be paired with the other device, without that you cannot connect.

Once paired you can try to connect to that phone. However that phone needs to be listening for incoming BT connections.

Usually you cannot connect 2 devices twice with eachother. Once one BT connection is established, it has to suffice.

What you can do with files etc depends on the permission your app has been granted.

Once connected you have an incoming and an outgoing bytestream on each device. You can code any kind of communication or protocol with those 2, its up to you.

Comment: If we didnt send any data means how much time the listening will be there? Even using the `BluetoothServerSocket` class.